# ImageView source load from another class

Tags: android, class, imageview, extend

sorry for the question but i'm newbie in Android,
I want to change the source of a ImageView calling another class, but the application closes.

The source code:

```
public class JugarActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jugar);
    int nivel = 1;

    Niveles crearnivel = new Niveles();
    crearnivel.CrearNivel(nivel);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_jugar, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

The class:

```
public class Niveles extends JugarActivity {
ImageView pregunta = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePregunta);
ImageView respuestaA = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageRespuesta1);
ImageView respuestaB = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageRespuesta2);
ImageView respuestaC = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageRespuesta3);
ImageView respuestaD = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageRespuesta4);

public void CrearNivel(int nivel) {
    if(nivel == 1) {
        pregunta.setImageResource(R.drawable.pregunta1); 
        respuestaA.setImageResource(R.drawable.pregunta1_a); 
        respuestaB.setImageResource(R.drawable.pregunta1_b); 
        respuestaC.setImageResource(R.drawable.pregunta1_c); 
        respuestaD.setImageResource(R.drawable.pregunta1_d); 
    }
}
}
```

What's wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: General way of solving this problem: look at the log generated in LogCat to see what is wrong. There will probably something explaining the issue, and why the app closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of extending Activity class you can create create an constructor for passing current Activity context for accessing imageView in non class. change your classes as :

```
public class Niveles {
Activity activity;

public Niveles(Activity activity){
  this.activity=activity;
}

ImageView pregunta = (ImageView)activity.findViewById(R.id.imagePregunta);
ImageView respuestaA = (ImageView)activity. findViewById(R.id.imageRespuesta1);
ImageView respuestaB = (ImageView)activity. findViewById(R.id.imageRespuesta2);
ImageView respuestaC = (ImageView)activity. findViewById(R.id.imageRespuesta3);
ImageView respuestaD = (ImageView)activity. findViewById(R.id.imageRespuesta4);

public void CrearNivel(int nivel) {
    if(nivel == 1) {
        pregunta.setImageResource(R.drawable.pregunta1); 
        respuestaA.setImageResource(R.drawable.pregunta1_a); 
        respuestaB.setImageResource(R.drawable.pregunta1_b); 
        respuestaC.setImageResource(R.drawable.pregunta1_c); 
        respuestaD.setImageResource(R.drawable.pregunta1_d); 
    }
}
}
```

and pass Activity context as to Niveles:

```
Niveles crearnivel = new Niveles(this);
crearnivel.CrearNivel(nivel);
```